# Resize the text inside a div when the viewport's width is less than the div's width -- i.e. keep div from being wider than viewport

Tags: javascript

I've written a function that should dynamically resize the text inside a div when the viewport's width is less than the div's width. Since the div's width is dependent on the width of its content this should actually *prevent* the div from ever being visibly wider than the viewport.

I've got this sort of working but the problem I'm having is that none of the browsers I've tested on seem to calculate the width of the div (#basics) correctly: when I log the calculated width the result displayed is always smaller than what it actually is if I measure the visible pixels myself. The result is that the resizing of the text begins too late and some of it ends up being off-screen and that horrible horizontal bar shows up.

I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong. Why is the width of the #basics div being calculated wrong?

I've written a jsFiddle but I can't get it working. I think the problem is that I'm not sure how to do window.onload and window.onresize on jsFiddle. Also my choices on the drop-down menus at the top left might be wrong... I have no idea. You're welcome to take a look at it and tell me what I'm doing wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/XUmU2/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="basicsContainer">
  <div id="basics">
     <p class="left">I'm a graphic/web designer/developer.</p>I'm <span style="font-size: 96%;" class="origin">originally </span>
     <span style="font-size: 92%;" class="origin">from </span>
     <span style="font-size: 88%;" class="origin">Brazil, </span>
     <span style="font-size: 84%;" class="origin">but </span>
     <span style="font-size: 80%;" class="origin">I </span>
     <span style="font-size: 76%;" class="origin">studied </span>
     <span style="font-size: 72%;" class="origin">in </span>
     <span style="font-size: 68%;" class="origin">the </span>
     <span style="font-size: 64%;" class="origin">USA </span>
     <span style="font-size: 60%;" class="origin">before </span>
     <span style="font-size: 56%;" class="origin">moving </span>
     <span style="font-size: 52%;" class="origin">to </span>
     <span style="font-size: 48%;" class="origin">Denmark, </span>
     <span style="font-size: 44%;" class="origin">then </span>
     <span style="font-size: 40%;" class="origin">Norway, </span>
     <span style="font-size: 36%;" class="origin">then </span>
     <span style="font-size: 32%;" class="origin">back </span>
     <span style="font-size: 28%;" class="origin">to </span>
     <span style="font-size: 24%;" class="origin">Denmark... </span>

     <p style="margin-left: 4.8%;" class="left">what some would call a "citizen of the world."</p>
     <p style="margin-left: 23%; margin-top: 1.7%;" class="white left"><span class="brackets">[</span> I live in Copenhagen and this is how I roll <span class="brackets">]</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font-family: arial, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div#basicsContainer {
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    // #f7f5e9 #f7f8f4 border-bottom: 1px solid $darkestGreen;
    padding-bottom: 1.2em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-image: url("../images/pattern1.png");
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 1px #797979;
}
div#basics {
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 110%;
    line-height: 130%;
    display: inline-block;
    color: $lightGreen;
    text-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #303a22, 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border: 1px solid red;
}
p.left {
    text-align: left;
}
span.origin {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
span.brackets {
    font-size: 135%;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var fontResizeDynamic = function () {

    percentageB = viewWidthPx / basics_width;

    if (basics_width > viewWidthPx) {
        basics.style.fontSize = (basics_fontSize * percentageB) + 'px';

    } else {
        basics.style.fontSize = 110 + '%';
    }

};

window.onload = function () {

    viewWidthPx = document.body.clientWidth;

    basics = document.getElementById('basics');
    basics_fontSize = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(basics, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));
    basics_width = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(basics, null).getPropertyValue('width'));

    fontResizeDynamic();

};

window.onresize = function () {

    fontResizeDynamic();

};
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are not just using media queries?

Comment: I don´t want the text to change size depending on screen resolution. I want it to change size only when the original size no longer fits the width of the monitor. This will always be different depending on the monitor´s resolution.